# android ormlite - storing string array

Tags: android, arrays, string, ormlite

I want to persist a class which contain String array.
How to do it in ormlite?
For example,

```
class A {
    int age;
    String[] childrenNames = new String[2];
}
```

Answer (score 10):

First you make the class Serializable. 
You can optionally add the table name at the top of the class by annotation.

then for the variables you have to add the database field annotation. In case of the string array you also have to annotate it as a Serializable datatype. 
You will get something like this:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "A")
Class A implements Serializable{

    @DatabaseField
    int age

    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.SERIALIZABLE)
    String[] childrenNames = new String[2];
}
```

Also dont forget to create getters and setters for each of the variables.

Comment: Serialization on the `A` class doesn't help the issue and is misleading.

Comment: why does class A have to be serializable?

Comment: There's no need to make A extend Serializable.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to persist a class which contain String array. How to do it in ormlite? For example,

You could store this as a serialized stream for sure.

However, a better way to do this is to use a `ForeignCollection`.  ORMLite does not do the magic fu that other ORM libraries do to support arrays.  Maybe it should.  In the meantime, here are the docs on setting up another table for your children-names:

> http://ormlite.com/docs/foreign-collection

One table would be for `A`.  Another table would be for the `ChildrenName`.  Each `ChildrenName` entity would have a foreign-field of `A` which would show which `A` each name corresponded to.

Comment: Foreign-collection don't seem to cover "many-to-many" case. One might still want to store an array of foreign row id's.

Answer (score 2):

@Gray told the better way todo.

@ForeignCollectionField(eager = false)
    ForeignCollection orders;

From docs:
In the above example, the @ForeignCollectionField annotation marks that the orders field is a collection of the orders that match the account.

The field type of orders must be either ForeignCollection or Collection – no other collections are supported because they are much heavier with many methods to support.